# Improving Time Complexity of "increment the number represented as an array of digits"

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

**Problem**
Given a non-negative number represented as an array of digits,

add 1 to the number ( increment the number represented by the digits ).

The digits are stored such that the most significant digit is at the head of the list.

Example:

If the vector has [1, 2, 3]

the returned vector should be [1, 2, 4]

as 123 + 1 = 124.

**My Code**

```
def plusOne(A):
    num = 0

    for digit in A:
        num = num*10 + digit

    retnum = num + 1

    retA = []

    while retnum > 0:
        retA.append(retnum % 10)
        retnum /= 10

    return retA[::-1]
```

Well, I am getting the correct answer by this.
However, I am not satisfied by the code's time complexity.
Suggestions for improving this code will be appreciated.

Comment: You will never get time complexity less than `O(n)` here, while `n` is the `A` length. So be satisfied.

Comment: Indeed. Adding 1 to 99999 will necessarily have to visit every element, so O(N) is the best you could possibly get

Comment: If the list has random access (i.e. it does not take O(n) just to get the last element), you can probably get _the average complexity_ down by not turning it into a number before but doing any carry-overs manually.

Comment: @Eugene Sh, can't you get a complexity O(1) most of the time (when the last digits are not all 9) ? It would then be something like amortized O(1) ?

Comment: @Tony then we have to do some assumptions on the input. And the question doesn't clearly state what kind of complexity we are talking about. I have a feeling, that the OP is meaning the efficiency of the function, not the time complexity *per se*

Comment: Another question: Is the method _supposed_ to return a copy of the list, or can/should the list be modified in-place? If copy is required, then there's _obviously_ no way to get it below O(n).

Comment: If you code it smartly (least-to-most significant with break on no carry), the amoritized cost of incrementing from 0 to 10^N is O(1). For N=4, there are 1.111,1 elements visited per increment on average. For N=5, 1.111,11. N=6, 1.111,111, so it's always less than O(2)=O(1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The complexity of your method is O(n) and you cannot do better in terms of big-o complexity in the worst case.

Changing the big-o complexity is not the only thing that matters however. Big-o notation does not take into account multiplicative and additive *constants*, this does not mean that such *constants* do not affect the performance of your algorithm. In your code, for instance, you are performing 2 O(n) cycles. In the first loop you do some arithmetic operations while in the second one you use `append` which has amortized worst case O(1) but that (citing from the docs):

> [...] rely on the "Amortized" part of "Amortized Worst Case". Individual actions may take surprisingly long, depending on the history of the container.

You could perform the same operations in place with (I think) smaller *constants*. For instance:

```
i = len(A) - 1

while i >= 0 and A[i]==9:
  A[i]=0
  i=i-1

if i >= 0:
  A[i] = A[i]+1
else:
  A.insert(0,1)
```

The first loop takes O(n) time in the worst case (all 9s). In the average case, however, the loop takes less than O(n). When we exit the loop in the worst case we need to insert an element at the beginning of the list which has *non-amortized* O(n) complexity.

In the average case this approach should be faster, but *it does not change the worst case O(n) complexity*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for introducing me to these concepts. As a beginner programmer, I have always been curious regarding the multiplicative and additions constants.

Answer (score 2):

You can't improve `O(n)` time-complexity because if the input is all 9s then you have to change `n` nines to zero and prepend one at the beginning:

```
def increment(digits):
    for i in reversed(range(len(digits))):
        if digits[i] != 9:
           digits[i] += 1
           break
        else:
           digits[i] = 0
    else: # no break, all 9s
        digits.insert(0, 1) #
```

Example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> increment(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 4]
```

The array grows in "all 9s" case:

```
>>> a = [9, 9, 9]
>>> increment(a)
>>> a
[1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code already has an O(n) time complexity.
So I dont think there can be any better time complexity than that.
However, as pointed in the above answers there are methods to improve the overall efficiency of your code.